# Json.NET Serialize private members and not readonly properties

Tags: c#, json.net

How can I customize Json.NET to serialize private members and NOT serialize public readonly properties (without using attributes).

I've had a stab around at creating a custom `IContractResolver` but am a bit lost.

Answer (score 12):

For a partial answer, messing with DefaultContractResolver.DefaultMembersSearchFlags can get it to include private things:

```
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings jss = new Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings();

if (includePrivateMembers)
{
    Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.DefaultContractResolver dcr = new Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.DefaultContractResolver();
    dcr.DefaultMembersSearchFlags |= System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic;
    jss.ContractResolver = dcr;
}

return Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(o, jss);
```

Seems to work on a lot of objects, though with some this seems to generate a CLR exception.

Comment: Worked for me. +1. How can I now specify what properties to exclude? A regex option would be even better.

Answer (score 4):

In response to [Chris' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14781014/806690), the `DefaultMemberSearchFlags` property on `DefaultContractResolver` [was deprecated as of version 6](http://json.codeplex.com/releases/view/117958). Despite of what the deprecation message says, I believe you'll need to overwrite the `CreateProperties` method, too, like [L.B explains](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24107081/806690).

This method gives you full control, including excluding readonly properties:

```
class PrivateContractResolver : DefaultContractResolver
{
    protected override List<MemberInfo> GetSerializableMembers(Type objectType)
    {
        var flags = BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic;
        MemberInfo[] fields = objectType.GetFields(flags);
        return fields
            .Concat(objectType.GetProperties(flags).Where(propInfo => propInfo.CanWrite))
            .ToList();
    }

    protected override IList<JsonProperty> CreateProperties(Type type, MemberSerialization memberSerialization)
    {
           return base.CreateProperties(type, MemberSerialization.Fields);
    }           
}
```